Cannot find save location of macbook screen-recording
I screen recorded for like an hour and a half. Afterwards, I accidentally dragged & dropped the video (the one that shows up in the UI on macbook in the bottom-right side of the screen, right after you stop screen recording) into the input of a desktop chat application. I did not want to send the video to that person, so I clicked on the x shown on the video, top-right.
Now, I cannot find my video at all... it seems it got deleted. I checked /Users/ionutmnt/Library/Containers/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX/Data/Library/Autosave Information but see it nowhere there...
Could anybody help me locate it, please?
